# How to prove in Lean that sums are distributive?

Tags: lean, type-theory, inductive-type, lean3, calculus-of-inductive-constructions

Assume we are given three types in Lean.

```
constants A B C : Type
```

There is a canonical map of the following form.

```
definition can : sum (A × B) (A × C) → A × (sum B C) := 
  λ x , sum.cases_on x  (λ y : A × B, ⟨y.fst, sum.inl y.snd⟩) 
                        (λ y : A × C, ⟨y.fst, sum.inr y.snd⟩)
```

I believe that this map should have an inverse (according to B. Jacobs book *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* page 143 coproducts in type theory are automatically distributive). I have trouble constructing the inverse in Lean, because I do not understand how sum.rec works, and I have trouble relating Jacobs *unpack P as ...* notation to the inductive definition of sums in Lean.

Can someone show me how I can define the inverse of can in Lean using sum.rec?

Comment: You can use triple backquotes (\`) to enclose your code. That makes them easier to visually distinguish and copy.

Comment: For what it's worth, Lean 3's mathlib contains both directions of this result as [`equiv.prod_sum_distrib`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/equiv.prod_sum_distrib), for which the interesting implementation is [here](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/50c30283a05ef81505edddaa01c4cf30a89e1005/src/logic/equiv/basic.lean#L1195) (with `A` on the right instead of left)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely the most idiomatic option is the equation compiler:

```
variables {A B C : Type}

open sum

def can : sum (A × B) (A × C) → A × (sum B C)
| (inl ⟨a, b⟩) := ⟨a, inl b⟩
| (inr ⟨a, c⟩) := ⟨a, inr c⟩
```

It may also be worth writing the forward map like this:

```
variables {A B C : Type}

open sum

def can : sum (A × B) (A × C) → A × (sum B C)
| (inl ab) := ⟨ab.1, inl ab.2⟩
| (inr ac) := ⟨ac.1, inr ac.2⟩
```

as it probably has a better definitional expansion (Lean 3 doesn't have definitional eta, Lean4 does). I wonder if it's now clear how to write the inverse now, I'll attach it below if not:

> ```
>  def nac : A × (sum B C) → sum (A × B) (A × C)
>  | ⟨a, inl b⟩ := inl ⟨a, b⟩
>  | ⟨a, inr c⟩ := inr ⟨a, c⟩
> ```

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it works. Thx! I would be especially interested to understand how the notation above expands into the recursor of sum. If you have time, could also explain how I can define nac using nat.rec?

Comment: *sum.rec or sum.rec_on

Comment: You can see the full term mode using the `#print` command, e.g. `#print nac`

Comment: I will say that I honestly don't know what term mode I'd expect from this!

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out how to write the inverse using @sum.cases_on. The rules of @sum.cases_on in lean are nearly identical as the rules of match in Jacobs book. The code is:

```
definition can (α : Type) (β : Type) (γ : Type)
  : sum (α × β) (α  × γ) → α × (sum β γ) := 
  λ x , sum.cases_on x  (λ y : α × β, ⟨y.fst, sum.inl y.snd⟩) 
                        (λ y : α × γ, ⟨y.fst, sum.inr y.snd⟩)

definition nac (α : Type) (β : Type) (γ : Type)
  : α × (sum β γ) → sum (α × β) (α × γ) :=
  λ v : α × (sum β γ), 
    sum.cases_on v.snd 
      (λ b : β, sum.inl ⟨v.fst,b⟩) (λ c : γ, sum.inr ⟨v.fst,c⟩)
```

I admit that it does not look as good as the version of It'sNotALie.